# In Google Cloud Endpoints, how is it possible to query the nearest points to a given coordinate?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

In MongoDB for a coordinate (lat, lng), we can describe a circle of radius R around it and determine which points are inside this circle using [centerSphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) method.

Withoud using MongoDB, is it possible to efficiently query those points using only [Google Cloud DataStore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the AppEngine Search service. You need to index your content into 'documents' first but then you can use a geopoint query to find the appropriate data.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_geopoint_fields